# Closed formula for computing Implied Volatility from Local Volatility function

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, stochastic-calculus, local-volatility

The main result of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227624117_Asymptotics_and_Calibration_in_Local_Volatility_Models) (*Asymptotics and Calibration in Local Volatility Models*, Berestycki, Busca, and Florent. Quantitative Finance, 2002) is equation (16) on page 63, that states that:

In the limit $\tau \rightarrow 0$, the implied volatility is the harmonic mean of the local volatility, namely

$$\lim_{\tau \rightarrow} \frac{1}{\phi(x,\tau)}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{ds}{\sigma(sx,0)}$$

where $\phi(x,\tau)$ is the implied volatility, $x=\ln(S/K)+r\tau$, $\tau$ is time to maturity, $\sigma(K,T)$ is the Local Volatility, $K$ is strike, $S$ is spot.

Suppose that for $\tau \rightarrow 0$ the Local Volatility is given by the following equation.

$$f(x)=\sqrt{\sigma_0^{2}+2\rho\alpha\sigma_0 x+\alpha^{2}x^{2}}$$

where $\sigma_{0}, \rho,\alpha$ are constants.

How can I compute the Implied Volatility from this Local Volatility equation, based on the formula above provided in the aforementioned paper?
I do not see how to apply the formula in practice. For example, what are the integration limits that I should use?